# Crash after opening PhpStorm on macOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos, kernel, phpstorm

After updating macOS Catalina from Beta 2 to Beta 3, I can't open PhpStorm or Android Studio ( I think apps used JAVA ).

That will be crash and below is report of that crash:

```
Path:                  /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.PhpStorm
Version:               2019.1.3 (PS-191.7479.51)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           phpstorm [3410]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-07-07 21:16:49.226 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A501i)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        2BB851C3-640F-AFB5-CF9A-1E889C101F0A


Time Awake Since Boot: 7000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        35  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000105c31000-0000000105c36000 [   20K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm

Application Specific Information:
CGDataProviderCreateWithData: 0x0 0

abort() called

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff711ff396 mach_msg_trap + 10
.
.
.
```

[Full logs at here](https://pastebin.com/zbb7PXgu)

Please help me how can I solve this instead downgrading macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After about 2 hours searching on the Google, I found below solution and it will fix the PhpStorm issue.

> Add -Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu into Help | Edit Custom VM Options and
>   restart IDE.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1639

Comment: phpStorm is not starting at all then how can I add the above solution? Could you please share the details?

Comment: Does the PhpStorm open and close after loading the project? @SachinKRaj

Comment: @SachinKRaj Here you can see how to edit VM Options from file : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: Thank you Mohammadreza, I was able to sort out issue. Below are the steps:

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @mohammadreza-yektamaram , I was able to sort out the issue. In my case Material theme was not able to support the new Catalina OS things. So I had to uninstall the plugins and settings manually to sort it out. Below are the steps I followed:
(Ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519 )

Delete all these directories: **Please note this will remove all the preferences, settings, etc**

- Configuration (idea.config.path): `~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Caches (idea.system.path): `~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Plugins (idea.plugins.path): `~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`
- Logs (idea.log.path): `~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Start phpStorm now and it should work fine. Then you can apply the workaround given above.

> Add -Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu into Help | Edit Custom VM Options and
>   restart IDE.